# How can I disable only being able to extrude along the blue axis of a face?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Regarding the extrude tool in edit mode, when I want to extrude it does so only along the blue axis of the face by default. How do I disable this?

[image]

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extrude Tool* works along the *face normal*, by default (that's what the blue axis shows).
You can change the orientation and direction through the pop-up menu.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help!!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.